# How to stop data binding on page load in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I delete a subcategory. I want them to bind only on a button click. How to stop the datasource and repeater from binding on first page load ?

```
 DataTable dtCategory = system.GetDataTable("Select * from TBLCATEGORIES where SubCategoryID=" + CategoryID);
            if (dtCategory.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                rpCategory.DataSource = dtCategory;
                rpCategory.DataBind();
            }

      if (Process == "Delete")
        {
            DataTable dtProducts = system.GetDataTable("Select COALESCE(COUNT(1),0) as TOTAL from TBLPRODUCTS where CategoryID = " + CategoryID);
            if (dtProducts.Rows[0]["TOTAL"].ToString() == "0")
            {
                SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("data source=localhost;initial catalog=Optima; Integrated Security=SSPI;");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from TBLCATEGORIES where CategoryID=" +  Request.QueryString["CategoryID"] );

                try {
                     cnn.Open();
                     cmd.Connection=cnn;
                     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   

                }

                catch(Exception ex) {
                     lblMsg.Text = ex.Message;
                }

                finally {  
                     cnn.Close(); 
                     DeleteMsg.Visible = true;

                }
         }
                else  {
                   InfoMsg.Visible=true;
                }
```

Comment: by checking IsPostback?

Comment: when i add postback , i cant see data after deleting..

Answer (score 0):

on Page_Load Check for page is post back or not `if(Page.IsPostBack)` then bind the data you want to bind!